# How to call references in c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, paypal

**ERROR:**
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PayPal' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to use the paypal library and it works in localhost, but i'm trying to use on the webserver (godaddy), how can i import and use them.

```
Line 3:  using System.Linq;
Line 4:  using System.Web;
Line 5:  using PayPal;
Line 6:  using PayPal.Api.Payments;
Line 7:  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Comment: Have you checked `bin` folder on the server and see if the paypal dll files are there?

Comment: i had it to the website folder, but it must be in the main folder. tanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, i had to paste the folder "bin" wich has the dll references in the main folder of the webserver.